# Wordpress editor-style.css not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add an editor-style.css file so I can change the editor styles to match my template.

I've added the following to the top of my functions.php file:

```
    function my_theme_add_editor_styles() {
    add_editor_style( 'editor-style.css' );
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'my_theme_add_editor_styles' );
```

This isn't working though, am I putting it in the right place?

```
/* ========================================================================================================================

Required external files

======================================================================================================================== */

require_once( 'external/starkers-utilities.php' );

/* ========================================================================================================================

Theme specific settings

Uncomment register_nav_menus to enable a single menu with the title of "Primary Navigation" in your theme

======================================================================================================================== */

add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');

// register_nav_menus(array('primary' => 'Primary Navigation'));

/* ========================================================================================================================

Actions and Filters

======================================================================================================================== */

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'starkers_script_enqueuer' );

add_filter( 'body_class', array( 'Starkers_Utilities', 'add_slug_to_body_class' ) );

/* ========================================================================================================================

Custom Post Types - include custom post types and taxonimies here e.g.

e.g. require_once( 'custom-post-types/your-custom-post-type.php' );

======================================================================================================================== */


add_editor_style( $stylesheet ); /* ========================================================================================================================

Scripts

======================================================================================================================== */

/**
 * Add scripts via wp_head()
 *
 * @return void
 * @author Keir Whitaker
 */

function starkers_script_enqueuer() {
    wp_register_script( 'site', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/site.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'site' );

    wp_register_style( 'screen', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style.css', '', '', 'screen' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'screen' );
}   

/* ========================================================================================================================

Comments

======================================================================================================================== */

/**
 * Custom callback for outputting comments 
 *
 * @return void
 * @author Keir Whitaker
 */
function starkers_comment( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment; 
    ?>
    <?php if ( $comment->comment_approved == '1' ): ?>  
    <li>
        <article id="comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">
            <?php echo get_avatar( $comment ); ?>
            <h4><?php comment_author_link() ?></h4>
            <time><a href="#comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>" pubdate><?php comment_date() ?> at <?php comment_time() ?></a></time>
            <?php comment_text() ?>
        </article>
    <?php endif;
}
```

Comment: Question 1) Where are you putting the editor-style.css file? Question 2) Is this a Child Theme? Question 3) If this is a child theme, is the parent theme employing its own editor stylesheet? If so, is the name of the file the same as the one you have defined?

Comment: Additionally, "not working" doesn't tell us much. Is the defined editor stylesheet showing up in the web inspector at all?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_editor_style - the first parameter is the Path to a stylesheet file, relative to the current theme directory, or an array thereof to link multiple stylesheet files. If a child theme is used, both the current child and parent theme directories are considered

Comment: The editor-style.css is in the theme directory and I'm not using a child theme.

Comment: You might find more experts and a better chance of getting your question answered over on the WordPress StackExchange site: [WordPress Answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Is it in the root of the theme directory? Or is it in a sub-directory? My guess is that you probably followed the Codex to the letter and put it in the root, but it's best to make sure. Try also renaming the stylesheet to something else, as 'editor-style.css' could be a protected name (not sure).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    /*
     * This theme styles the visual editor to resemble the theme style,
     * specifically font, colors, icons, and column width.
     */
    add_editor_style( array( 'css/editor-style.css', twentysixteen_fonts_url() ) );

    // Load regular editor styles into the new block-based editor.
    add_theme_support( 'editor-styles' );

    // Load default block styles.
    add_theme_support( 'wp-block-styles' );
```